# How can I distinguish between different BadRequest errors with Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 has a large number of [reasons](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) why it will return an HTTP 400 Bad Request error.  Most relevant is the fact that some of these errors are from the unreliability of the internet, such as a request timeout. Another reason it might be returned is if the bucket or key name is invalid.

I am attempting to upload files to S3 with key names supplied by a customer-controlled key name.  I need to be able to distinguish between a transient 400 error such as a timeout and a bad key/bucket name error that will not be transient. A transient error will indicate we should retry that upload, while a non-transient error means we should cease trying to upload that file.

However, I do not know how to distinguish between these two errors! If it matters, I am attempting to use the [JetS3t](http://www.jets3t.org/) API to perfom these uploads. How can I distinguish between a bad key/bucket name error and anything else with a 400 error code?

Answer (score 1):

Read the response body.

From the page you cited:

> The body o[f] the response also contains information about the error.

Parse the response body that accompanies the http error code.  An explanation of the error is almost always spelled out in XML in the response body.

Example nonsense request (nothing edited here, this is exactly what I used for a GET request to generate this error):

```
http://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAEXAMPLEEXAMPLE&Signature=bogus&Expires=1500000000
```

Response:

```
<Error>
 <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
  <Message>
   The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
  </Message>
 <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAEXAMPLEEXAMPLE</AWSAccessKeyId>
 <RequestId>...</RequestId>
 <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

You'll find a pretty close correlation between this content and the list of possible errors.

Now, technically, that's a 403 not a 400, it's just the first idea I came up with for an easily handcrafted nonsense request to generate an error, but any S3 error should generate a comparable response.

Comment: Ah, I'll have to see if the various 3rd party APIs allow me to get that information.  One in python I was using for various testing did not appear to give me that information.  I'll upvote/accept once I know this will work with the Jets3t API.

Comment: I found a way to do this using jets3t. However, I don't have access to the XML response in that library.  If you can find a way to access the raw XML response in that library for a bad key name (try "..\\") I'll accept/upvote this answer.

Comment: While perhaps not precisely meeting the definition, I consider this a form of [error hiding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding), a definite anti-pattern.  It baffles me why so many libraries seem to not bother to make such critically useful information available, and that was one of my early motivations for writing so many of the AWS libraries I use from scratch, using only the API documentation.  It certainly took longer to get things going but the payoff is that I am rarely surprised by errors.